# Upload json file to php server in android

Tags: php, android, web-services

I am uploading my json file to php server but it gives me **file not found**. I have created it dynamically and it shows me in device. I have given same path. I am referring this https://coderwall.com/p/zjuwbg.

**Code**

```
       final String uploadFilePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        final String uploadFileName = "MyJson.json";
    FileObj = new File(uploadFilePath+"/"+uploadFileName);
                        System.out.println("file object : "+FileObj);
                        System.out.println("My file name: "+uploadFilePath+""+uploadFileName);
                        //uploadFile(uploadFilePath + "" + uploadFileName,userid);
                        StringBuffer responseBody=new StringBuffer();
                        Log.i("", "Ready to upload file...");
                        HttpClient client=new DefaultHttpClient();
                        client.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
                        Log.i("", "Set remote URL...");
                        HttpPost post=new HttpPost("http://sripadamarketing.com/awarenessu/Data/");
                        File file = new File(uploadFilePath+"/"+uploadFileName);
                        MultipartEntity entity=new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
                        ContentBody cbFile = new FileBody(file, "application/json");         
                        Log.i("emotinal awareness", "Adding file(s)...");

                        try {
                            entity.addPart("param", new StringBody("sync"));
                            entity.addPart("u", new StringBody(userid));
                            entity.addPart("jsonf", cbFile);
                            //entity.addPart("jsonf", new FileBody((FileObj), "application/json"));
                        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        //entity.addPart("uploadedfile2", new FileBody((FileObj), "application/zip"));
                        Log.i("emotinal awareness", "Set entity...");
                        post.setEntity(entity);
                        BufferedReader bs=null;
                        try
                        {
                         Log.i("emotinal awareness", "Upload...");
                          HttpEntity hEntity=client.execute(post).getEntity();
                          bs=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(hEntity.getContent()));
                          Log.i("emotinal awareness", "Response length - "+hEntity.getContentLength());
                          String s="";
                          while(s!=null)
                          {
                            responseBody.append(s);
                            s=bs.readLine();
                            Log.i("emotinal awareness", "Response body - "+s);
                          }
                          bs.close();
                        }
                        catch(IOException ioe)
                        {
                         Log.i("emotinal awareness", "Error on getting response from Server, "+ioe.toString());
                          ioe.printStackTrace();
                          responseBody.append("...");
                        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try one of these libraries they are very good for such kind of tasks

https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http

Or

https://github.com/koush/ion

Comment: You might want to be a bit careful; if those links ever go down, this answer will end up looking rather silly.

Comment: thank you very much for the advise. It will be better if you concentrate on the question he asked instead of posted answers.